# Show section onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<section id="one">

<form>
<input type=text />
<button id=btn>Go</button>
</form>

</section>

<section id="two" >
<h1>Hi</h1>
</section>
```

I have the above html which has two sections.Im trying to hide the section with id `"two"` hide and show section `"one"`.When i click on `go` button,section `one` should fade and section "`two`" should be shown.

Can some one help me code the jquery for this?

Im new to jquery.It would be helpful.

I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/x8B8c/

please dont ask what I have tried,im a fresher to javascript and html as well,I would like to know how this can be done

Comment: if you are a fresher read [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) documentation/[api](http://api.jquery.com/)/(learn jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/) and see what can be done....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x8B8c/1/

Comment: in terms of some pointers see dom ready handlers, click handler and show/hide etc

Comment: @adeneo You deserve an upvote for an immediate answer!

Comment: Note that a button inside a form submits the form, so you have to either change the buttons type or prevent the form from submitting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<section id="one">
 <input type=text />
 <button id=btn>Go</button>
</section>

<section id="two" style="display:none">
 <h1>Hi</h1>
</section>
```

JQuery Script

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
 $('#one').hide('slow')
 $('#two').show('slow');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x8B8c/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
 $('#two').hide(1000);
  $('#one').show(1000);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyjose009/x8B8c/7/)

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
   $('#one').hide();
   $('#two').fadeIn();
});
```

I have used [jQuery on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#two').fadeIn();
    $('#one').hide();
    });  

     });
```

Comment: .on works fine out of ready function

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, use `.fadeOut()` for section 1 and `.fadeIn()` for section 2.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#one').fadeOut();
    $('#two').fadeIn();
});
```

**Fiddle DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/x8B8c/2